# Mac freeze and shutdown randomly

Tags: shutdown

Since months my mac shutdown at random moments , i couldn't find any specific app that made it.
Can you guys help me ? = (
Also my mail keep opening randomly , i saw that it's about google calendar but i can't find a fix that works for me .

Thank you very much
here is the logs :

```
    panic(cpu 10 caller 0xffffff7f9879dad5): userspace watchdog timeout: remoted connection watchdog expired, no updates from remoted monitoring thread in 60 seconds, 719 checkins from thread since monitoring enabled 14420 seconds ago after wakeservice: com.apple.logd, total successful checkins since wake (14420 seconds ago): 1442, last successful checkin: 10 seconds ago
service: com.apple.WindowServer, total successful checkins since wake (14420 seconds ago): 1442, last successful checkin: 10 seconds ago

Backtrace (CPU 10), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff92457db820 : 0xffffff8017d3bb2b 
0xffffff92457db870 : 0xffffff8017e734d5 
0xffffff92457db8b0 : 0xffffff8017e64f4e 
0xffffff92457db900 : 0xffffff8017ce2a40 
0xffffff92457db920 : 0xffffff8017d3b217 
0xffffff92457dba20 : 0xffffff8017d3b5fb 
0xffffff92457dba70 : 0xffffff80184d2b25 
0xffffff92457dbae0 : 0xffffff7f9879dad5 
0xffffff92457dbaf0 : 0xffffff7f9879d7e6 
0xffffff92457dbb10 : 0xffffff801846739b 
0xffffff92457dbb60 : 0xffffff8018470443 
0xffffff92457dbca0 : 0xffffff8017e22d12 
0xffffff92457dbdb0 : 0xffffff8017d419d8 
0xffffff92457dbe10 : 0xffffff8017d18635 
0xffffff92457dbe70 : 0xffffff8017d2f0e5 
0xffffff92457dbf00 : 0xffffff8017e4b575 
0xffffff92457dbfa0 : 0xffffff8017ce3226 
    Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
        com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[053A5D15-51D4-3E61-978B-EB435FA4BD0A]@0xffffff7f9879c000->0xffffff7f987a4fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: watchdogd
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19D76

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.3.0: Thu Jan  9 20:58:23 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.81.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: A8DDE75C-CD97-3C37-B35D-1070CC50D2CE
Kernel slide:     0x0000000017a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8017c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8017b00000
System model name: MacBookPro15,1 (Mac-937A206F2EE63C01)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 50759035529426
last loaded kext at 117095427123: @filesystems.smbfs    3.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f9e59d000, size 446464)
loaded kexts:
us.electronic.kext.vusb 119.66
us.electronic.kext.vic  119.66
com.bitdefender.mdrnet  10.23b151
com.bitdefender.mdrfp   13.23b1
com.bitdefender.devmac  1.0.18b38
com.mice.driver.Xbox360!C   1.0
us.electronic.kext.elogger  119.66
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4.1
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@fileutil   20.036.15
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    3.0.5
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    3.0.5
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.5
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.7.2
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.7.2
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.3f5
>pmtelemetry    1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>AGPM   111.4.2
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.4
>AGDCBacklightControl   4.7.2
@kext.AMD9500!C 3.0.5
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.66
>!ABacklight    180.1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.66
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!AMuxControl2  4.7.2
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.424
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.4
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.13
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>usb.!UHostBillboardDevice  1.0
>usb.realtek8153patcher 5.0.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@filesystems.apfs   1412.81.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!UAudio    320.49
>usb.!UEHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UEHCI 1.2
@kext.AMDRadeonX4100HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  3.0.5
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  4.7.2
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
>usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
>usb.serial 6.0.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.5
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!AGraphicsControl  4.7.2
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    810.1
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>!AActuatorDriver   3430.1
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.3f5
>!AMultitouchDriver 3430.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3430.1
|IONDRVSupport  569.4
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.3f5
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.3f5
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.7.2
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.3.1
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   569.4
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.2
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.5
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.5
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.5
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.0
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.80.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   810.1
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.3f5
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.3f5
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first step is removing all those third-party extensions:

```
us.electronic.kext.vusb 119.66
us.electronic.kext.vic  119.66
com.bitdefender.mdrnet  10.23b151
com.bitdefender.mdrfp   13.23b1
com.bitdefender.devmac  1.0.18b38
com.mice.driver.Xbox360!C   1.0
us.electronic.kext.elogger  119.66
```

Some of this looks to be a thing called Flexihub:

https://www.flexihub.com/wiki/user-guides/flexihub/flexihub-devkit/driver-installation-mac.html

And also Bitdefender:

https://www.bitdefender.com/consumer/support/answer/1784/

and some Microsoft Xbox360 controller. 
https://howtoremoveapp.com/howtoguides/uninstall-xbox-360-controllers-driver-on-mac/

and then test to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Hi, thank for your answer , these 3 apps were already install way before the first time this bug happened .

Comment: @echo55 Have you updated the OS since? That might have broken these apps. Nevertheless, removing thrd-party kexts is a valid first step in troubleshooting.

Comment: unfortunately except the xbox driver i can't delete them , it's my company's apps.
i did update every single time there were an update.

Comment: If this is a company-managed Mac, you should contact your IT dept for help.

Comment: you know how it is right ? i'll have to wait 2 months for maybe just a little thing
In the logs there were only these informations ? do you guys see anything else ?
I can't read much of it

Answer (score 0):

I have fought with same problem and in my case, the cause was the Google File Stream.

[macOS Catalina watchdog timeout kernel panics](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390620/macos-catalina-watchdog-timeout-kernel-panics)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove Flexihub kexts (`us.electronic.kext.vusb / us.electronic.kext.vic`) by running these commands

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/us.electronic.flexihub.daemon.plist
sudo rm -f /Library/LaunchDaemons/us.electronic.flexihub.daemon.plist
sudo pkgutil --forget us.electronic.pkg.flexihubd

sudo kextunload -b us.electronic.kext.vusb
sudo kextunload -b us.electronic.kext.vic
sudo kextunload -b us.electronic.kext.elogger

sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/evhci-10_09.kext
sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/evhci-10_11.kext
sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/evic-10_09.kext
sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/evic-10_10.kext
sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/elogger.kext
sudo pkgutil --forget us.electronic.pkg.vusb-driver

sudo rm -rf /Library/Application\ Support/FlexiHub

sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Flexihub.framework
```